# Steam on ubuntu 14.04 Error. Can't isntall Steam

Tags: steam

It displays a dependency error after I tried to install it on 14.04. This is a fresh install and I have tried to install from both the valve website and the ubuntu software centre. It fails in either case.

The error it comes up with the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
steam-launcher: Depends: jockey-common but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)